# mysql to append a number of stars based on the string length

Tags: mysql

I have a requirement that when a string length is less than 10, I need to append as many stars(*) at the end till length equals to 10.

ex:

```
ipString = "Stack"

opString  = "Stack*****"
```

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use <kbd>[**`RPAD`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_rpad)</kbd>

```
SELECT RPAD('STACK',10,'*')
```

More accurately:

```
SET @str := 'Stack ';

SELECT 
IF(LENGTH(@str) < 10, RPAD(@str,10,'*') ,@str)
```

<kbd>[**WORKING DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/71847/1)</kbd>  <sup>If the length of the string is less than 10</sup>

<kbd>[**WORKING DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/71851/1)</kbd>  <sup>If the length of the string is greater than or equal to 10</sup>

---

**Note on `RPAD`:**

**Description**

`MySQL RPAD()` function pads strings from right. The actual string which is to be padded, length of the string returned after padding and string which is used for padding - all these are passed as arguments.

**Syntax**

```
RPAD(str, len, padstr)
```

**Arguments**

```
Name    Description
str     The actual string which is to be padded.
len     Length of the string returned after padding.
padstr  String which will be used for padding.
```

Comment: Glad to hear that. If you ever need to append `*` at the beginning then use `LPAD` instead of `RPAD`.